# Is there anything similar to Laravel tinker in .NET Core world?

Tags: .net-core

I want to play around with ***LINQ*** in .NET Core,
but I couldn't find anything similar to Laravel tinker.

Comment: Hi Mo'ath Zaghdad and welcome to SO, Can you please tell us what you tried so far and what is not working in more details

Comment: Hello Tamir Klein, and thank you,
I found (https://www.linqpad.net) it looks very good but I'm a Linux user so I can not use it.
I want a way of testing and trying LINQ command.
I'm used to using Laravel tinker to mess around with the application and the eloquent Models, so I was hoping that I could find something similar in the .net

Comment: You can give [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) a try... even more specific here's another [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RCgTqH)

Comment: @PeterSchneider just an FYI, Tinker runs your commands in the context of your app, so when you run a Tinker shell you have access to your project's stuff like models, services, etc. 
Fiddles aren't the same thing.